# Tkinter entry widget execution

Tags: python, tkinter

So I made a simple program however it doesn't seem to work
my code is:

```
e = Entry(root, font = 20,borderwidth=5)

e.grid(row=1)


def capture(event):
    print(e.get())
     
e.bind("<Key>", capture)
```

However the first time I enter something in the box, all I get is an empty string.

Comment: You can try `e.bind("<Key>", lambda event: e.after(1, capture, event))` or simply bind `"<KeyRelease>"` or use a control variable like `StringVar` along with `trace` method.

Comment: Why do you ask the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246191/entry-widget-in-tkinter) again?

Answer (score 1):

As @Art stated:

You can use `"<KeyRelease>"`, `e.bind("<Key>", lambda event: e.after(1, capture, event))"` or simply Use `StringVar()`

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
e = Entry(root, font = 20,borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=1)
def capture(event):
    print(e.get())
e.bind("<Key>", lambda event: e.after(1, capture, event))
root.mainloop()
```

Or you can use a `StringVar()`

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
s=StringVar()
e = Entry(root,textvariable=s, font = 20,borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=1)
def capture(*args):
    print(s.get())
s.trace("w",capture)
root.mainloop()
```