# What is returned by .get() on an empty Tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to check if necessary values are entered properly before running a code. To do this, I want to check that the user has actually entered something into both entry widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

entry1_val = None
entry2_val = None
def submit_cmd():
    global entry1_val, entry2_val
    entry1_val = entry1.get()
    entry2_val = entry2.get()

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text='Entry 1:')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = ttk.Label(root, text='Entry 2:')
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(root)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

submit = ttk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit_cmd)
submit.grid(row=2, column=1)

# pseudocode for what I want to check
"""
if(entry1_val == something or entry2_val == something):
    print("Didn't enter both values")

"""
root.mainloop()
```

I was previously doing this by a simple if statement that checks if both `entry1_val` and `entry2_val` have been updated from the `None` object. Like so:

```
if(entry1_val != None and entry2_val != None):
    print('Both values good')
elif(entry2_val == None):
    print("Didn't enter 1st value")
```

However, since `submit_cmd` updates both `entry1_val` and `entry2_val`, even if the user has only entered a value into one of the entry widgets, both values get updated from `None`.

I am wondering two things:

- What is returned when `.get()` is called on an empty entry widget
- Is there a better way to check that something was correctly entered into the entry widget?

Comment: ```''``` a blank string. Of course, you can trace it. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251222/tkinter-entry-widget-execution/68251338#68251338

Comment: Thank you @Sujay, I thought I had tried this but apparently I didn't try it correctly, I feel a little silly now. The blank string works perfectly for what I was trying to do.

Comment: A tip for next time: try using: `print(repr(entry1_val))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't enter anything into your tk.Entry, it will contain a `''` by default..

example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
print(repr(entry.get()))
root.mainloop()
```

output:
`''`
it is because you didn't enter anything to the entry..

Comment: Instead of `print(entry.get())` use `print(repr(entry.get()))`. It will more clearly show what's in the variable.

Comment: No problem. I find the `repr` function very useful when debugging programs

Comment: haha, i don't user `repr` AT ALL! anyways, have a nice day.